# Remove duplicate </li> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page, generated by a server that has bad LI elements, with two closing li tags

```
<li>Whatever</li></li>
```

All jQuery operations work fine in Firefox, but not in IE (7 and 8). I want to remove the duplicate `</li>` before I start my functions, how do I do it?

Comment: And to be clear, you are not in control of the server such that you could make it output proper markup?

Comment: How about fix the html that is generated by the server rather than putting a band-aid on it.

Comment: You can't do this. Your browser will (probably) fix up the duplicate `<li>` tags before jQuery has a crack at it. Your DOM can't contain invalid markup. By the time your markup has been built into a series of nested DOM nodes, it has been scrubbed of broken tags. I say "probably" because feeding invalid markup to your browser is more or less [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: is html being retireved by ajax? could be fixed if it is, but is bandaid to bad server code

Answer (score 4):

Not possible to fix via the client, unless you have a browser that defies logical sense. jQuery controls the DOM, not the raw HTML, and as a result, it can't edit the scrubbed broken tag. Just fix your server-side script.

If you really want a hacky, terrible, awful JS solution, you can AJAX request the page itself after that page is loaded, remove the AJAX call from the page (to avoid an infinite loop), remove the broken elements and then load that HTML in a new window. PLEASE never do that.

Answer (score 1):

If possible you should of course fix the code that generates the page.

If that's not possible, you have a rough road ahead. You can't fix the markup, because it's parsed before you can do anything about it, so you have to fix whatever the browser generated from the broken markup.

Each browser will have a different way of handling the incorrect code, so you have to test every possible browser that you can get your hands on, including every current version of Internet Explorer (7, 8, 9, 10 and possibly 6). That is a pain in the ass, as you can only have one version of IE installed at a time. Luckily you can use the developer tools in newer versions to simulate older versions, however it's still not a 100% accurate emulation.

Some browsers may ignore the extra ending tags, and some amy add extra list elements. You have to write code that handles whatever each browser generated from the markup, and fix the elements.